# PHP: Step-by-step forms with POST

Tags: php

How can I make "step-by-step" screens with `$_POST` method, with optional levels inside? this is my code:

```
<?php
    $next = @$_POST['next'];
    $prev = @$_POST['prev'];

    if( !isset($next) || isset($prev) ) {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optional-checkbox" id="oc" />
    <label for="oc">If you'll check me, you'll see an optional level</label>
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

<?php
    }
    else {
        // if isset next
        $oc = @$_POST['oc'];
        if( isset($oc) ) {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    You've checked the optional checkbox. now you can continue, or - go back.
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

<?php
        }
        elseif {

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <?php 
        // check if we came from the "oc" level, if true - show special message, else - just continue
        if( $oc == true ) {
            echo 'You\'ve checked the optional checkbox. now you\'re on the 3rd level.';
        }
        else {
            echo 'now you\'re on the 3rd level.';
        }
    ?>
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

        }
    }
```

When I test it, its not showing levels properly and I can't continue from the optional level to the next level. I sure did something wrong, but I don't know what... also, I can't go back - if I'll unset `$_POST['next']`, it will send me to the first level, from every level. any suggestions/ thoughts?

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you mean like a wizard type form where you fill stuff out, then click next and get a different form, etc. then submit it?

Comment: if you wand to show different forms on clicks jquery will do the job. Make some divs and check for the user input. If the user press next with jquery change the div etc etc

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: Yes, @Rafael Shkembi: I am aware of the js/jquery solutions but I prefer `PHP` in this case

Comment: @natanel97 - I would prefer client side in this case ( javascript ).  To do this in PHP will mean you have to store partial data between form submissions, and have separate forms on their own pages for each chunk.  Using JS, you can have one big from, then just hide/show portions of it.  There is no way in PHP ( severside ) to modify the page without making another request to the server, and because of the stateless nature of the internet, you'll need to keep that data somewhere between requests.  IMO Javasript is the right tool for this job.

Comment: Also for performance reasons I would avoid this  `$next = @$_POST['next'];`, not to mention you have no guarantee what the value will be when it is not set, instead do this `$next =  isset($_POST['next']) ? $_POST['next'] : false;`  Then you can be sure its boolean false, or input.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix well I guess you guys right maybe I should do this with JS/ jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, as much as I love PHP, it's not the answer for everything.  Go with the simplest solution, chances are you'll thank yourself latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code has some syntax errors.

**Error 1 and the Important one**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="optional-checkbox" id="oc" />
```

Name of your checkbox must be `oc` not 'optional-checkbox' because here `$oc = @$_POST['oc'];`, you are looking for input with name `oc`.

**Error 2**

```
<?php
    }
    elseif {
```

Your `elseif` has no condition. it should be `else` only and you missed a `?>` immediately after the `elseif{`.

**Error 3**

```
</form>

    }
}
```

Here you missed `<?php` tag between `</form>` and `}`

**Working Code**

```
<?php
    $next = @$_POST['next'];
    $prev = @$_POST['prev'];
    if( !isset($next) || isset($prev) ) {
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="oc" id="oc" />
    <label for="oc">If you'll check me, you'll see an optional level</label>
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else {
    // if isset next
       $oc = @$_POST['oc'];
        if( isset($oc) ) {
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    You've checked the optional checkbox. now you can continue, or - go back.
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <?php 
        // check if we came from the "oc" level, if true - show special message, else - just continue
        if( $oc == true ) {
           echo 'You\'ve checked the optional checkbox. now you\'re on the 3rd level.';
        }
        else {
            echo 'now you\'re on the 3rd level.';
        }
    ?>
    <button name="prev" type="submit">Previous</button>
    <button name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I would point out this `$next = @$_POST['next'];` ( error suppression ) is probably not the best way to handle optional parameters.  Good work on the other errors, mixed content ... yuck